# SSRS - Problem when i remove HTTP configuration from Report Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

When I remove HTTP configuration of Report Server Configuration Manager:

- WEB SERVICE URL
- WEB PORTAL URL

[WEB SERVICE URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wNTI.png)
[WEB PORTAL URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIcxd.png)

I having the follow issue:

[hmm... can't reach this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C1Y5.png)

Anyone knows why this can happens?

PS.: If add HTTP configuration, SSRS works normaly.

I appreciate any help.

I tried to reconfigure everything, but nothing happened.

I tested removing HTTP configuration in 2 different instances (on the same server) and it worked normally.

I tested removing HTTP configuration on another server and it worked normally too.